# react error - _this2.props.updateShelf is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I spend two days and I can't figure it out. I tried with bind or something but maybe I can not use it. So, please help me. I have another components but I have error with this part of code.
When I try move book from shelf to shelf I have this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
at onChange (Book.js:12)
When I wasn't use bind I had this error - Book.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.updateShelf is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Book extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="book">
        <div className="book-top">
          <div
            className="book-cover"
            style={{
              height: 192,
              width: 128,
              backgroundImage:
                "url(" + this.props.book.imageLinks.thumbnail + ")"
            }}
          />
          <div className="book-shelf-changer">
            <select
              value={this.props.book.shelf}
              onChange={event => {
                this.props.updateShelf(event, this.props.book);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" disabled>
                Move to...
              </option>
              <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>
              <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
              <option value="read">Read</option>
              <option value="none">None</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="book-title">{this.props.book.title}</div>
        <div className="book-authors">{this.props.book.authors}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Book;

import React from "react";
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import * as BooksAPI from "./BooksAPI";
import Search from "./Search";
import "./App.css";
import BooksList from "./BooksList";

/* eslint-disable */
class BooksApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    books: []
  };

  updateShelf = (event, book) => {
    BooksAPI.update(book, event.target.value).then(result => {
      BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => {
        this.setState({ books: books });
      });
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => {
      this.setState({ books: books });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="app">
          <Route
            path="/search"
            render={() => <Search updateShelf={this.updateShelf} />}
          />

          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={({ history }) => (
              <BooksList
                books={this.state.books}
                updateShelf={this.updateShelf}
              />
            )}
          />
          <div className="open-search">
            <Link className="" to="/search">
              Search a book
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default BooksApp;

import React from "react";
import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Shelf from "./BookShelf";
import "./App.css";

/* eslint-disable */
class BooksList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    bookShelfs: [
      { id: "currentlyReading", title: "Currently Reading" },
      { id: "wantToRead", title: "Want to Read" },
      { id: "read", title: "Read" }
    ]
  };

  getBooksByFilterShelf = shelf => {
    return this.props.books.filter(book => shelf.id === book.shelf);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-books">
        <div className="list-books-title">
          <h1>MyReads</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="list-books-content">
          <div>
            {this.state.bookShelfs.map(shelf => (
              <Shelf
                key={shelf.id}
                shelf={shelf}
                books={this.getBooksByFilterShelf(shelf)}
                updateShelf={this.props.updateShelf}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BooksList;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Iga! Could you include the `BooksList` component as well? It's hard to say what might be wrong without seeing that.

Comment: does you book class have a constructor?

Comment: @Tholle Hi, I add BooksList component

Comment: @JayLane Hi, i tried to use constructor but like always I had a error maybe I did it wrong way.

Comment: @IgaTroubles You have to include all relevant code where you are using `Book`. You are not using `Book` in `BooksList` either, only `Shelf`.

Comment: @Tholle right, thanks. I've figured it out :) thanks for help.